# Robert Harvey's reputation history is lying?

Tags: support

There were no net reputation changes that day, but it says -2. I don't know if it's appropriate to ask this, but what happened? And why is it lying?
[image: t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-2 is a couple downvotes, which I don't think are public to other users. Could also be something like a suggested edit being accepted then later deleted. Voting fraud can also sometimes cause weird reputation changes. Back then, reputation was sometimes recalculated after the fact, so it wasn't always clear how it tied to an action.

Comment: So they downvoted two answers